# extract tail of a line

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Given a log ,we need to find every line of the form `Time taken to process  Request54`; and then extract the numeric after 'Request'.
In the above case ,the desired value is 54.
How do we achieve this with a single line shell script.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
echo "Time taken to process  Request54" | grep -Po "(?<=Time taken to process  Request)\d+"
54
```

where you use `grep` in `perl` mode, with the output matching exactly the regex not the whole line where a match is found. 
The regex itself:

```
(?<=Time taken to process  Request)\d+
```

uses a positive lookbehind on `Time taken to process  Request` and matches `\d+`

Comment: So aren't you even going to wait for OP to share their efforts and just provide free code?

Comment: @Inian: I have answered a bit too early :( Sorry

Comment: There's almost certainly a much better way to do whatever it is the OP is trying to do (I can think of several possibilities) but now the OP won't get to find out what that is since she got this answer before she had a chance to provide the missing information necessary for us to provide the right answer.